# AMS117 ADJ - Is it possible to control output voltage using DAC

Tags: voltage-regulator, dac

I have tried to answer this question myself but unfortunately analog electronics is not my strongest point. Just thinking if it is possible to control output voltage of the AMS117 ADJ using DAC output.

Comment: You will probably find more if you Google LM317 DAC.

Comment: yes, but you give up the feedback, making it unregulated. if you can control the resistence instead, you can keep the feedback and the control set-point

Comment: Thank you. I know that, but I plan to connect output to one of the ADC ports and actively regulate it using uC and DAC.

Comment: @dandavis I think you will still get feedback built-in. It will regulate to DAC voltage + 1.25 volts.

Comment: @AHL: yes, but offest DAC voltage is not the same as that seen by the load, my only point...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can feed your DAC voltage into the adjust pin of the regulator. Keep in mind that the DAC voltage will have a 1.25V offset. [Here](https://youtu.be/CIGjActDeoM?t=6m51s) is a part of a video about it.